# Locale error when doing sudo operations

Tags: locale

When I do some super user operations, like upgrading the system, I get these warnings:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_PAPER = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_TIME = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

Do you know how can I get rid of it? I want the system in en_US

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sudo vim /etc/default/locale` to add the missing lines:

```
LANGUAGE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Then reboot your system and everything should be fine.

Comment: Sorry, but that answer is bad advice, even if it happens to make the reported error go away. Neither `LANGUAGE` nor `LC_ALL` needs to be set, so you drew the wrong conclusion from the wording of the error message. Furthermore, if you want to set the `LANGUAGE` variable, you should give it a colon separated list of language codes; a complete locale name including the `.UTF-8` part is plain wrong. Another thing is that in case of a desktop, you should never set `LC_ALL` persistently, since it screws up the related GUIs. (Possibly the OP has a server.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the number formats, date/time formats etc. in US style, you can edit the `/etc/default/locale` file and make it contain only the line

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Otherwise you can generate the missing German locale:

```
sudo locale-gen de_DE.UTF-8
```